# How to Backup a disk with corrupted GPT?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, backup, fdisk, gpt

My hard disk is failing. Booting into Live Ubuntu, `fdisk -l` says "GPT table is corrupt, Backup appears okay, using it".

I need to take a backup of the files on the disk ASAP. It doesn't show in the file manager.

Comment: First repair gpt:
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html
More repair info  use p, v & w to write the partition table. If not correct just use q to quit. :
http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802